# Passing Reference with PHP

Tags: reference

as you can see i am very new in PHP world.

I am able to show my Mysql table list but i want to add some link to show some further information but i couldnt get id reference on address bar.

on the below line something wrong buty i couldnt find it

```
echo <a href=details.php?ref=" .$row['id']. "> .$row['name']."</a>";
```

this is the address i get on address bar

http://test.com/new/details.php?ref=

as you can see i did not receive id , If i put ID manualy code works and shows details

I appreciate your help

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try

`echo "<a href='details.php?ref=" .$row['id']. "'>" .$row['name']."</a>";`

Comment: Thanks for your reply but the link still   http://test.com/new/details.php?ref=                   without ID

Comment: try print_r($row) and see $row has. Maybe your sql query not retrive data

Comment: i receive 
Passanger 102Array ( [0] => Passanger 102 [name] => Passanger 102 )   as you can see i dont get ID

Comment: As you see not 'id' key in array. Get data with tihs code `$row = mysql_query("select * from table_name")`

Comment: I ve just noticed that in my query i ve put ONLY name i ve added ID and it works !!!!! Cok tesekkurler yardimin icin